# Can I change toolbar language in grapesjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grapesjs

I use grapejs, and I need to change the text language. There is 'i81n' for labels, but I couldn't find anything for inputs like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v49dz.png) as you can see i change the label language with i18n but selectbox's options are still english Also if it's possible, As you can see [in the](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r14rN.png) pic I need to change the placeholder for text input and the title 'text' above it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found how to change inputs. You have to change your props one by one. You can find the details in
https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/issues/2712#issuecomment-615763048

And for the second issue you have to add your i18n file domComponents. in my scenario it's like this

```
var _default = {domComponents: {
names: {
  '': 'Kutu',
  wrapper: 'Gövde',
  text: 'Metin',
  comment: 'Yorum',
  image: 'Görsel',
  video: 'Video',
  label: 'Etiket',
  link: 'Link',
  map: 'Harita',
  tfoot: 'Tablo alt',
  tbody: 'Tablo gövde',
  thead: 'Tablo başlık',
  table: 'Tablo',
  row: 'Satır',
  cell: 'Hücre'
}...}..}
```

Document for this is here : https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/I18n.html#plugin-development